# Problema em remover elemento de uma lista encadeada

Tags: java, lista-encadeada

Estou implementando uma lista encadeada em Java. Entretanto, a função de remover está me causando alguns problemas, mas especificadamente a parte de remover no meio da lista. A minha lista é composta apenas por um campo do tipo inteiro que possui uma nota.

```
public void remove(int nota)
{
    Aluno ante = null;
    Aluno posi = this.first;

    while(posi.getNota() != nota)
    {
        ante = posi;
        posi = posi.getProximo();
    }


    if(posi == null)
    {
        System.out.println("Valor não encontrado");
        return;
    }

    if(posi == this.first)
    {
        this.first = posi.getProximo();
        posi = null;
    }
    else if(posi.getProximo() == null)
    {
        ante.setProximo(null);
        posi = null;
    }
    else
    {
        ante.setProximo(posi);
        posi = null;
    }
    this.tamLista--;
}
```

Onde está o erro? Não consigo identificar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um jeito mais simples é utilizar um método recursivo. Dessa maneira, você passará como parâmetro o primeiro elemento da lista e a nota que você deseja procurar para remover. Um exemplo:

```
Aluno removeAluno(Aluno aluno,int nota){

  if(aluno != null){

      // Se o aluno atual for o aluno que você deseja remover, ele é substituido pelo aluno seguinte
     if(aluno.getNota() == nota){

      aluno = aluno.getProx();

     // Se não for, a função é chamada novamente, passando o próximo aluno como parâmetro
    }else{

        aluno.getProx() = removeAluno(aluno.getProx(), nota);
    }
  }

  return aluno;
}
```

**Exemplo de execução:**

**Lista:** Aluno(nota:10)-> Aluno(nota:8)-> Aluno(nota:6) -> Aluno(nota:5)

**Procurar nota == 6**

Execução:

1. `Aluno(nota:10) = removeAluno( Aluno(nota:10), 6)`
2. `6 == Aluno(nota:10).getNota()` ----> **false**
3. `Aluno(nota:10).getProx() = removeAluno( Aluno(nota:8) , 6)`
4. `6 == Aluno(nota:8).getNota()` ----> **false**
5. `Aluno(nota:8).getProx() = removeAluno( Aluno(nota:6) , 6)`
6. `6 == Aluno(nota:6).getNota()` ----> **true**
7. `Aluno(nota:6) é substituído por Aluno(nota:5)`

Agora começa a recursão, o `Aluno(nota:5)` que acabou de substituir `Aluno(nota:6)`, é devolvido para as chamadas anteriores. Fazendo de traz pra frente:

1. `Aluno(nota:8).getProx() = Aluno(nota:5)` ou seja: `Aluno(nota:8)-> Aluno(nota:5)`
2. `Aluno(nota:10).getProx() = Aluno(nota:8)` ou seja: `Aluno(nota:10)-> Aluno(nota:8)`
3. `Aluno(nota:10) = Aluno(nota:10)` ou seja, o primeiro elemento da lista continua sendo Aluno(nota:10)

Se olharmos a lista agora, ela estará desse jeito:

**Lista:** Aluno(nota:10)-> Aluno(nota:8)-> Aluno(nota:5)

Comment: Não consegui implementar o código recursivo, pois na seguinte linha:
aluno.getProx() = removeAluno(aluno.getProx(), nota);
Obtenho um erro: the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Comment: @Vinicius, A classe Aluno deve conter um aributo `int nota` e um atributo `Aluno proximoAluno`. Portanto o método `getProx()` deve retornar o valor de `proximoAluno` de um objeto `Aluno`.  Você está implementando desta forma?

Comment: @Vinicius, ao invés de fazer atribuição direta, ou seja, **x = y**, crie métodos **set** na sua classe **Aluno**, dessa forma, quando você quiser substituir um nó pelo outro, faça `aluno.set(outroNoAluno)`.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, não é possível fazer algumas operações em listas em tempo de execução.
Por exemplo, se a lista estiver dentro de "for" encadeados não é possível remover. É preciso mudar a lógica para conseguir chegar no seu objetivo.
Tem como postar o log com o erro para verificar melhor?